# Positioning parent element so child is in exact same position

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, css-position

I'm trying to implement a drop-down in JS. I have a div container with bunch of items in it. I want to make it into a dropdown so when the dropdown is clicked to open, the item currently selected will stay exactly in the same place and other items will be displayed above and below it.

I started out with this structure:

```
   <div>this is some random paragraph of text or any other content where dropdown will be positioned
    <div class="dropdown"><ul>          
          <li>aaaaa</li>
          <li class="selected">b fdfb</li>
          <li>cccc</li>
          <li>dd</li>
          <li>cccc</li>
          <li>eee</li>
          <li>ffff</li>
          <li>gggg</li>
          <li>hh</li>
          <li>iiiii ii</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
         and this is more
   </div>
```

Only one item is displayed somewhere e.g. inside of paragraph of text. The problem I have is that when dropdown is open I find it hard to match position of div.dropdown (displayed with all the children) so the item currently selected item will be positioned exactly in the same place.

How would I best approach this?

EDIT: [Created Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vvz1dx31/) as that might give you better idea of what I'm after

Comment: Do you have the CSS and Javascript that goes with this HTML markup? If you add it to your question, so that you have a small, "working" example of your issue, it would be a lot easier for people to help you.

Comment: yes, I created a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/vvz1dx31/ thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a few issues here:

1. The drop-down will take up more vertical space than the text in it's parent container when it is opened. This means that it will shift when opened because the line-height of the parent is not large enough for the expanded drop-down. Set the `line-height` of the parent `<div>` to something larger (like 1.5em or so) to fix this.
2. The horizontal width is unstable because the text values are of different lengths. You'll need to set all of them to the same width to keep the text to the right from shifting when a different-length item is selected.
3. The text shifts down by 2 pixels when the drop-down is selected. This is probably a byproduct of some browser styles that are being applied. Changing the line:

`t = liTop - Math.ceil(this.$ul.offset().top) + 15;`

to

`t = liTop - Math.ceil(this.$ul.offset().top) + 17;`

Fixed this problem.

Here is the updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vvz1dx31/5/ - Tested as working in Chrome 40, IE 11, and FF 36.